# UITableView cells grouped mess up when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've read a lot at stack about 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' problem, I tried several answers and I can't seem to fix it.
I'll appreciate if someone can find what is the problem in my code

PARTIAL CODE:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 2;
}
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
{
return 10;
}



- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)

{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

if (indexPath.section == 0)   {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [arrayOfQuestion objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        question1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 3, 280, 38) ];

        question1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        question1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        question1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];

        question1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        question1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;        // no auto correction support

        question1.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support

        question1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

        question1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault; // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)

        question1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        question1.tag = 0;

//            question1.delegate = self;



        question1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing; // no clear 'x' button to the right



        [question1 setEnabled: YES ];

        [cell addSubview: question1 ];

    }

}

else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [arrayOfQuestion objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        question2 = [ [ UITextField alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 3, 280, 38) ];

        question2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        question2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        question2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];

        question2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        question2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;        // no auto correction support

        question2.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support

        question2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

        question2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault; // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)

        question2.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        question2.tag = 1;

        //            listTitleTextField.delegate = self;



        question2.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing; // no clear 'x' button to the right



        [question2 setEnabled: YES ];

        [cell addSubview: question2 ];

    }

}

................

return cell;

}
```

Comment: I was trying to answer this question but I feel the code really needs to be rethought from the ground up.  A simple answer isn't possible.  I still have a few questions.  For one, what does 'mess up' mean?

Comment: When scrolling text fields override all cells

Answer (score 1):

Remember `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` reuses the same object over and over to draw your cells. It's more efficient than creating a new cell for an unknown number of rows in your table view.  This means as you add UITextFields with `[cell addSubview: ... ];` the next time you need that cell it will already have that subview added to it's view.

You're better off creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that has the `UITextField` already added and accessible as a property.  Then you can have two cell identifiers: one that refers to the question which is a basic `UITableViewCell` and one that refers to the answer, which is your new subclass.

On top of that, I'd look at making your code more flexible by refactoring the way you're building your table cells.  As it is it's not very scalable and I bet a nightmare trying to access the answers.